# Add pagination to existing Rails site?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pagination

So I have a Rails app with posts and categories, and as I'm having the website tested out by friends I realized I forgot to add any pagination to category pages, so once a lot of listings are added the page just keeps getting longer and longer which is obviously not ideal.

Here's the code on each category page that renders the listings:

```
<% notsold = @category.products.where("sold_value = false").order("created_at DESC") %>
        <% notsold.each do |f| %>
        <% if User.find(f.user_id).school == current_user.school %>
          <div class="listing">
            <a href="/users/<%= f.user_id %>" class="nounderline"><%= image_tag User.find(f.user_id).avatar.url(:thumb).sub('http://s3.amazonaws.com/anymarket/','http://anymarket.s3.amazonaws.com/'), :id => "categories_profile_picture", :width => "30", :height => "30" %></a><h4><%= link_to f.name, view_item_path(f.id) %></h4><% if f.photo? %><span id="camera-icon-preview" class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera preview_toggle" data-id="<%= f.id %>"></span><% else %><% end %><p><%= f.description[0..60].gsub(/\s\w+\s*$/, '...') %></p><p class="price"><%= number_to_currency(f.decimal_price, precision: 2) %></p>
          </div>
      <% else %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Div#listing is each individual listing.

The problem is I don't know how to preserve this code and add pagination. I'm looking for some advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

example from page:
In your controller like this:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

more examples:

```
## perform a paginated query:
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])

# or, use an explicit "per page" limit:
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)

## render page links in the view:
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Not sure but this should work out for you:

```
<% notsold = @category.products.where("sold_value = false").order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30) %>
        <% notsold.each do |f| %>
        <% if User.find(f.user_id).school == current_user.school %>
          <div class="listing">
            <a href="/users/<%= f.user_id %>" class="nounderline"><%= image_tag User.find(f.user_id).avatar.url(:thumb).sub('http://s3.amazonaws.com/anymarket/','http://anymarket.s3.amazonaws.com/'), :id => "categories_profile_picture", :width => "30", :height => "30" %></a><h4><%= link_to f.name, view_item_path(f.id) %></h4><% if f.photo? %><span id="camera-icon-preview" class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera preview_toggle" data-id="<%= f.id %>"></span><% else %><% end %><p><%= f.description[0..60].gsub(/\s\w+\s*$/, '...') %></p><p class="price"><%= number_to_currency(f.decimal_price, precision: 2) %></p>
          </div>
      <% else %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```